# How can I select the first element having a specific class regardless of position among siblings?

Tags: html, css

Please check the below code. First style is perfectly applied but not the second one for "regular 1". I have to apply blue color on the first element with class "regular".

```css
.plan-list .basic:first-child {
    background: red;
  }
  .plan-list .regular:first-child {
    background: blue;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="plan-list">
  <li class="plan basic">basic 1</li>
  <li class="plan regular">regular 1</li>
  <li class="plan regular">regular 2</li>
  <li class="plan basic">basic 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't select elements by index inside a class selector. You'd need scripting (jQuery would make it easy).

Comment: First apply your desired styles to all your elements with that class. Then "undo" the styles for elements with the class that come after the first one.
.plan-list li.regular { background: blue; } .plan-list li.regular ~ .regular { background: transparent; }

Comment: @SyamMohan, yes thanks.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
<style>
  .plan-list .basic:first-child {
    background: red;
  }
  .plan-list .regular:nth-child(2) {
    background: blue;
  }
</style>

<ul class="plan-list">
  <li class="plan basic">basic 1</li>
  <li class="plan regular">regular 1</li>
  <li class="plan regular">regular 2</li>
  <li class="plan basic">basic 2</li>
</ul>
```

This is because, while this li is the first child WITH THAT CLASS,
 it is in fact, the second child within its parent

Comment: This still targets elements by index, not by class and subindex. It probably can't be accomplished with CSS unless you rely on index.

Comment: This is a good point.  To target through subindex inside a parent you probably need some JS

Answer (score 0):

When you set `first-child` it literally means it must be the `first child` of its `parent`.

So, you are trying to select an element with class `regular` **AND** that is the `first child` of its `parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other answers, from MDN documentation:
The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents the first element *among a group of sibling elements*.